# only sumif checkbox is checked?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, checkbox, sum

How do I only sum the amounts that are checked on sheet2 for each name?

```
Sheet1
Column A
Tom
Susan


Sheet2             
Column A    Column B     Column C
 Tom         100         (un-checked)
 Susan       150         (checked)
 Susan       75          (un-checked)
 Tom         25          (checked)
 Susan       50          (checked)
```

Solved!

```
   =SUMIFS(Sheet2!B1:B,Sheet2!A1:A,Sheet1!A1:A,Sheet2!C1:C,true)
```

Output:

```
Tom   25
Susan 200
```

Comment: Use ```SUMIFS()```

Comment: Can you give an example pls? I still can't get it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMIFS(M2:M,A2:A,"Susan",N2:N,true)
```